# AngularJS improve ng-repeat performance with out pagination

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting around 1000 records from API. I want to show in the UI without pagination(We are having some other issues at this moment). I'm loading those records in the html using ng-repeat. ng-repeat is taking lot of time for rendering those page.I'm using 'track by id' also.

How can I improve ng-repeat performance? What are my options?

Comment: If you're doing any filtering on those records, avoid the DOM-based filter (e.g. `{{ amount | currency }}`), which triggers on each digest, and instead do the filtering in your controller with the `$filter` service. One-time binding (e.g. `{{::amount}}`) also reduces the watch load. Plus, if you've not already done so, try [disabling debug data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) for the production version of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use pagination, you should consider one time binding (see "One-time binding" section in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), or if that doesn't suit your needs, you can try https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier

However, this will still take some time to render, so you should consider simulating infinite scroll by using limitTo filter and increasing its value as you scroll down. If you want to display all 1000 items at once, it will always be slow, no matter how optimised.

Comment: Yes, I'm using :: one-time binding. still I'm seeing same issue.